# How to write multiple RouteValues?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagedlist

I have 3 search filters on my view page, so i need to pass parameter values to the query when going to another page. I've done it through this RouteValue = new KeyValue

The problem is I don't know how to add multiple parameters, except for statistical_entity I have two more

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PaginatorComponent", 
                            new 
                            { 
                                Module = "EsahsUsers", 
                                Page = "Index", 
                                HasPreviousPage = Model.HasPreviousPage, 
                                PageNumber = Model.PageNumber, 
                                PageCount  = Model.PageCount, 
                                RouteValue = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Statistical_Entity", Context.Request.Query["Statistical_Entity"])
                            })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
RouteValue = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", ""), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "") }
```

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
lambda_method(Closure , object , Object[] )

Comment: On component side what you pass ?

Comment: List<KeyValuePair<string, string>?> routeValue
pagingConfig.RouteValue = routeValue;

public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>?> RouteValue { get; set; }

Comment: And what is the value  in routeValue ?

Comment: null. what should it be?

Comment: It should be  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> type